# horizontal menu items not displaying inline

Tags: css

im trying to create a Horizontal menu:

CSS

```
 #menu {
        display:inline;
        float:right;
    }
    #menu > li {
        display:inline;
        list-style:none;
        width:40px;
        border-top:4px solid #FFFFFF;
        padding-top:20px;
        margin-top:25px;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div id="menu">
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
</div><!-- menu -->
```

i have added `display:inline;` but they are not displaying correctly with the `top-border` when i remove the `display:inline;` it works fine but they all display in a vertical list

Comment: I think you are missing something... http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `disply:inline-block;` for the `li` and just `float` for the `ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/c94hG/1/

*(I have changed the color of the border for display purposes. it was white)*

Comment: excellent - thank you. is there any way to make to top-border the same width as the text? jsfiddle.net/K5wQa/2

Answer (score 2):

You are missing UL tag. Now I have update your code. check below code

CSS

```
#menu {
        display:inline;
        float:right;
    }
    #menu > ul > li {
        display:inline;
        list-style:none;
        width:40px;
        border-top:4px solid #000;
        padding-top:20px;
        margin-top:25px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>HOME</li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- menu -->
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrEnx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a UL element, which basically says that the following list items are part of an un-ordered list.  Here it is in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VgRYv/

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>HOME</li>
    </ul>
</div>

ul#navlist li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block;` instead of `inline` (or, as alternative, apply a `float: left` to every `<li>`)

Comment: excellent - thank you. is there any way to make to top-border the same width as the text? http://jsfiddle.net/K5wQa/2/

Comment: instead of `padding-right:20px;` use `margin-right:20px;` and wrap your list-items inside an `<ul>` as @Alias pointed out

Comment: the text still seems to be a little longer than the top border? any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/K5wQa/3/

Comment: @CharlieFord nOW CHECK TO THIS DEMO I THINK you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/K5wQa/4/

Comment: @CharlieFord why are you not used to ul you used to direct li why Please used to ul than used li as like this <ul><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>

Comment: Ok cool - have sorted those bits. http://jsfiddle.net/K5wQa/6/ can I get the text aligned to the middle of the top border horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

add `float:left` to `li`,or add `display:inline-block` to `li`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#menu {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
#menu > li {

    list-style:none;
    width:40px;
    border-top:4px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin: 25px 8px 0 8px;
    float:left;
}
```